# How to feed further model parameters along the inputs to Tensorflow Estimator?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

**Short Version:**
I have a custom model with a layer which can be parameterized by a value `sigma`.

I am using this model with Tensorflow Estimator:

```
    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fun)
```

And for instance the training is declared as follows:

```
    # Train the model
    train_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": train_data}, 
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=nEpochs, shuffle=True)
    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,max_steps=nSteps)
```

In this setup, how can I pass `sigma` to my custom Estimator so that it can be trained / evaluated with different values?

---

**Longer Version:**

I am working on this DNN Autoencoder, for which I have a layer that adds Gaussian noise by considering random_normal() values from a distribution of known standard deviation sigma.

This is a model of a communication system, and the output logits (from the final layer) is retrieved using the model.predict() function, and my metric namely Bit Error rate is computed by a custom function in Tensor Flow 1.5, Python 3.5, Windows 10.

The problem is as follows:

1. I want to train the system for sigma=sigma1, and retrieve the output logits.(This part is fine, and I am able to get the desired output.)
2. I also want to predict the outputs for sigma=sigma2, sigma=sigma3, sigma=sigma4 and so on using the same Estimator that was defined(IN THE SAME PROGRAM).

My DNN looks like this and is defined in the model function:

1. Input Layer- One Hot Encoded Values are fed here.
2. Dense+ReLU
3. Dense+Linear
4. Normalization Layer
5. Addition of Noise: Here I add a tf.random_normal(stddev=sigma) to the output of the previous layer. This is where I would appreciate assistance in understanding how I can use different sigmas for each run(train/test). I suppose you could say sigma ought to be a parameter that can have different values for each test run.

   ```
    gnoise=tf.random_normal(mean=0,stddev=sigma) 
    Then the layer's output=norm(which is the prev layer's output)+gnoise
   ```
6. Dense+RELU
7. Softmax-Output is Logits

I define my estimator as:

```
    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fun)
```

And the training is declared as follows:

```
    # Train the model
    train_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": train_data}, 
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=nEpochs, shuffle=True)
    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,max_steps=nSteps)
```

The predict function is declared and called as:

```
    pred_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": test_data}, 
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=nEpochs, shuffle=False)
    pred_results = classifier.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn)
```

Comment: Please provide your code for the gaussian noise layer, so one can properly reply.

Comment: gnoise=tf.random_normal(mean=0,stddev=sigma)                                          Then layer's output=norm(which is the prev layer's output)+gnoise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your sigma a parameter of your layer, then feeds its value to your model at runtime through your `features` (distinguishing between `x` and `sigma` using the columns keys).

It is hard to reply precisely without your gaussian layer code, but supposing your model is defined in such a way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def gaussian_noise_layer(x):
    # Currently, your sigma is probably fixed somewhere here, e.g.
    sigma = 1

    dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=0., scale=sigma)

    # Build Gaussian kernel from dist:
    # gaussian_kernel = ...

    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x, gaussian_kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def model_fun(features, labels, mode, params):

    # Get input x from features:
    x = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params.feature_column)

    # ... building your model here, adding at some point the gaussian layer, e.g.
    # ... net = f(x)
    net = gaussian_noise_layer(net)
    # ... predictions = f'(net)
    # ...

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops
    )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ...

    # Specifying your params and inputs:
    params = tf.contrib.training.HParams(
        # ... other hyperparameters,
        # Define feature column for input x of shape "shape_x" (e.g. (64, 64, 3)):
        feature_column=tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="x", shape=shape_x)
    )

    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fun, params=params)

    # For training:
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(x={"x": train_data},
                                                        batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=nEpochs, shuffle=True)
    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=nSteps)
```

... then you would need to edit it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def gaussian_noise_layer(x, sigma):

    # sigma is now a parameter
    dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=0., scale=sigma)

    # Build Gaussian kernel from dist:
    # gaussian_kernel = ...

    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x, gaussian_kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def model_fun(features, labels, mode, params):

    # Get input x from features:
    x = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params.input_feature_column)
    # Get sigma from features:
    sigma = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, params.sigma_feature_column)

    # ... building your model here, adding at some point the gaussian layer, e.g.
    # ... net = f(x)
    net = gaussian_noise_layer(net, sigma)
    # ... predictions = f'(net)
    # ...

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops
    )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # ...

    # We now specify which columns contain the actual inputs (x), and which columns contain other parameters (sigma):
    params = tf.contrib.training.HParams(
        # ... other hyperparameters,
        # Define feature column for input x of shape "shape_x" (e.g. (64, 64, 3)):
        input_feature_column=tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="x", shape=shape_x),
        # Define feature column for input sigma of shape () i.e. scalar (default shape):
        sigma_feature_column=tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="sigma")
    )

    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fun, params=params)

    # Train:
    num_train_elements = train_data.shape[0]
    sigma = [1] * num_train_elements  # or e.g. sigma = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, ...]
    # We can now feed sigma along x:
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
         x={"x": train_data, "sigma": numpy.array(sigma)},
         batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=nEpochs, shuffle=True)

    classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=nSteps)

    # ...

    # Predict:
    sigma = [2] * num_train_elements  # or e.g. sigma = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, ...]
    pred_input_fn=tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
         x={"x": train_data, "sigma": numpy.array(sigma)},
         batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=nEpochs, shuffle=True)
    pred_results = classifier.predict(input_fn=pred_input_fn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you describe how I would go about adding different parameters sigma to the predict function declaration and call?

Comment: Also, it seems like TF expects the values of "x" and "sigma" declared in the train_input_fn to have the same shape. Is there a work-around as I want sigma to hold a single scalar value like 1,2,3 etc.?

Comment: 1) For predict, you just have to define its input the same way as for train, i.e. adding sigma (as a numpy element) to the dict for tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn. I updated my answer to add an example.
2) As you can see in the answer (I added comments to further clarify), the shapes of x and sigma are passed to TF when defining the feature columns in params. In the answer, x has a shape "shape_x" (e.g. (64, 64, 3)) and sigma has a default shape () i.e. is a scalar.

Comment: I meant that on following this code, I see this error:                                         ValueError: Length of tensors in x and y is mismatched. All elements in x and y must have the same length. x and y are the parameters of the numpy input function and can contain feature dicts. Which basically means that the numpy input function needs SNR and train_data to have the same size

Comment: Right, my bad. I forgot to expand `[sigma]` so that it has the same length as `train_data`, e.g. doing `[sigma_val] * train_data.shape[0]` (code has been updated). Indeed, in this implementation, a sigma value must be passed for every element in the training data (a positive aspect of this is that you could set different values of sigma for every element). Hope this helps.